# Primefaces 5.2 line chart ignores tickcount JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using line chart like this:

```
    <ui:define name="head">
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"/>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"/>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"/>
    </ui:define>
        <h:form>
        <p:chart type="line" widgetVar="chart" model="#{resultsViewController.areaModel}" style="height:300px" />
        </h:form>
```

In my bean I set up the line chart model:

```
    totalCounts = resultFacade.getTotalResult("day");
    areaModel = new LineChartModel();

    LineChartSeries count_up_series = new LineChartSeries();
    count_up_series.setFill(true);
    count_up_series.setLabel("count up");

    LineChartSeries count_down_series = new LineChartSeries();
    count_down_series.setFill(true);
    count_down_series.setLabel("count down");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    for(ResultsView result : getItems())
    {
        calendar.setTime(result.getDate());
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, result.getMinutes() * 5);
        count_up_series.set(calendar.getTime().toString(), result.getCountUp());
        count_down_series.set(calendar.getTime().toString(), result.getCountDown());

    }


    areaModel.addSeries(count_up_series);
    areaModel.addSeries(count_down_series);

    areaModel.setTitle("Area Chart");
    areaModel.setLegendPosition("ne");
    areaModel.setStacked(true);
    areaModel.setShowPointLabels(true);
    areaModel.setAnimate(true);

    Axis xAxis = new CategoryAxis("Date");
    xAxis.setTickCount(20);
    xAxis.setTickAngle(-50);
    areaModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);
    Axis yAxis = areaModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Count");
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(100);
```

However, the setTickCount method does nothing. I see lots of and lots of ticks.
I found some solutions that suggest using chartExtender however that does not yield any effect plus I checked what PF generates and it looks ok:

```
xaxis: {label:"Date",renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,tickOptions:{angle:"-50"},numberTicks:20}},series:[{label:'count up',renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,fill:true,fillAlpha:1.0,showLine:true,markerOptions:{show:true, style:'filledCircle'}},{label:'count down',renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,fill:true,fillAlpha:1.0,showLine:true,markerOptions:{show:true, style:'filledCircle'}}],stackSeries:true,animate:true,showPointLabels:true,datatip:true},'charts');});</script><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:16" value="5469798536346298278:5748043847734473197" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: why do you include charts.js yourself? and does it work when you do not include all the jqplot js files?

Comment: Well I read many posts about problems with p:chart and there were many suggestions that PF does not include the jqplot library correctly. So I include it as a precaution. However, I did of course test it without any includes

Comment: I've never seen posts that PF does not include the jqplot js correctly. And what you include IS the PF jqplot js, the way PF includes it to. Please post references where you read PF fails to do it correctly. And if the js files do not make a difference (positive or negative) remove them in your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835687/linechart-not-rendering-for-primefaces-5-0

Comment: I improved that answer and voted on it